# how to enable info layer in syslog?

Tags: debugging, syslog, rsyslog, filter, trace

syslog usually filter out output trace messages with predefined tag types like: `dbg`, `info`, `note`, `warn`, `err`, `crit`, `alert`, `emerg`, etc.

What is the proper way to enable/disable syslog filtering during fresh compiled software investigation?

The only way is to alter the file `/etc/rsyslog` or there is a command (a software) allowing dynamically enable/disable certain syslog level and so it would be easy to include into the batch file:

1. enabling certain syslog level messaging
2. executing tested application
3. restore original syslog levels

Comment: it's appeared that much easier is to configure and use syslog-ng instead of rsyslog one. detailed manual with examples on syslog-ng is available [here] (https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-pe-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-pe-guide-admin/html-single/index.html)

Comment: following is the complete list of user application level messages:

0  Emergency: system is unusable

1  Alert: action must be taken immediately

2  Critical: critical conditions

3  Error: error conditions

4  Warning: warning conditions

5  Notice: normal but significant condition

6  Informational: informational messages

7  Debug: debug-level messages